# Find the length of the longest diagonal of the bo

Tags: systems-of-equations, volume

The total length of all $12$ sides of a rectangular box is $60$.
The surface area of the box is given to be $56$.  Find
$(i)$ the length of the longest
diagonal of the box
$(ii)$ the volume of the box

---

Let the one of the sides be $a$ and the other be $b$
$$8a+4b=60 $$ and $$2a^2+4ab=56 $$
Solving theses I get values of $a=2/3$ and $b=16/3$ but they do not match with the answer given for longest diagonal$=13$
It is also given in the answer that the volume cannot be determined. But having got $a$ and $b$ we should be able to find the volume.

Comment: Surely this is a three dimensional box, no?

Comment: $12$ **edges**.

Comment: Why do we assume that the height coincides with one of the base lengths?

Comment: @arutoregni Please see my comment to lulu's answer.

Comment: @arutoregni Also, as I mentioned, even using your (based on an incorrect oversimplification) equations, you got the wrong solutions. You should have got $a = \frac{15 - \sqrt{141}}{3}$. You can work out $b$ from this, and if you calculate the diagonal as $\sqrt{2a^2 + b^2}$, you get the expected result of $13$.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that there are three dimensions, not two.  Call the side lengths $\{a,b,c\}$.  We have $$a+b+c=15\;\;\&\;\;ab+ac+bc=28$$

The longest diagonal is $d$ and we easily see $d^2=a^2+b^2+c^2$.  But then we compute:  $$225=(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+ac+bc)=d^2+56$$

Thus we can compute $d$.

I see no way to compute the volume...we have two equations in three unknown and the three lengths are not determined by the given data.

To be complete:  to see that the volume is not determined from the given data, we'll construct two boxes with different volumes that meet the constraints.  For the first we'll assume, as the OP does, that $a=c$.  That gives us $a=\frac 13\times \left(15-\sqrt {141}\right)=c,\;b=15-2a$. (Note:  this differs from the values given by the OP).  We quickly get volume $\sim 14.02$ in this case. As an alternative, let us suppose that $c=2a$.  Working numerically, we get $\{a,b,c\}=\{.69801,12.91,1.396\}$ and in this case the volume is $\sim 12.58$.

Comment: Your answer is correct. I believe the original poster's issue was mainly that  he assumed the box was a *square prism* and not a rectangular prism (or cuboid). Also, he messed up the algebra and got the wrong solutions to the equations (it's a fairly ugly surd if you work it out using his equations).